# find() on model gives id as string in one environment and int in other

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5 and have a model `Book`.

I have two environments - *dev* and *production*

On *dev*:
In `tinker`, when I do

```
Book::first()
```

It gives me

```
App\Book {
     id: 1,
     name: ...
```

On *produvction*:
The same thing gives me

```
App\Book {
         id: "1",
         name: ...
```

Notice the `id` is `int` in *dev* but `string` on *production*

Because of this, a condition like

```
if($id === $book->id)
```

which works correctly on *dev*, doesn't work on *production*.

Any idea why this is so? Is there a way I can make *production* environment to give me `int` instead of `string`?

**PS:**

1. I have installed Laravel on *dev* and then pulled the code on *production* via **git**. So my `composer.json` and `composer.lock` are exactly same on *dev* and *production*. So running `composer install` on *production* should give me same environment there as on *dev*.
2. I am using `mysql` database.
3. My *dev* environment is Laravel's `homestead`.
4. `Book` is just a dummy model I've used here. All my models behave in the same manner as explained above.

Comment: Not sure what the cause of this is, but setting up your own [cast](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting) for `id` might fix the problem.

Comment: Do you have the same version of php in your both environment?

Comment: @Amir Why didn't I think of that? I have different versions of php - `5.6.7` on *dev* and `5.5.9` on *production*. Is this the problem though?

Comment: @linuxartisan:Maybe,just give it a try

Comment: if($id == (int) $book->id)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously you don't want to do any manual casting as suggested in comment. It seems that on one server you miss [mysqlnd](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqlnd.php) extension (I need to assume you use MySQL because you haven't mentioned it in your question) what causes that all data types are returned as strings.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Could you please explain why you are suggesting against manual casting?

Comment: @linuxartisan Because it should work out of the box. On most systems int will be returned as int, so you don't do do it manually when you simply missing extension on the other one.

Comment: I just faced the same issue, not because I was missing the mysqlnd extension, but because I switched from MySQL to SQLite. So ensuring casting could indeed improve portability.