# How to get Laravel Query Builder result as integer

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel Query Builder to query MySQL database but it returns integer values as string values.

I have the following query.

```
$query = DB::table('store_products')->select('products.id', 'products.name', 'products.unit_type', 'products.price', 'products.image_path', 'products.is_popular', 'store_products.price AS store_price')
           ->join('products', 'products.id', '=', 'store_products.product_id')
           ->join('product_categories', 'product_categories.product_id', '=', 'store_products.product_id')
           ->where('store_products.store_id', $store_id)
           ->where('store_products.product_id', $product_id);
```

Here the query gets Product which is existing in `Store_Products` for given `store_id`.

The problem is, it returns `id` (which is the Primary Key for Product) as `string` when I use Query Builder. Looks like there is something wrong with casts.

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [find() on model gives id as string in one environment and int in other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38034996/find-on-model-gives-id-as-string-in-one-environment-and-int-in-other)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Casting is not a solution but a workaround to the problem. Your actual problem is missing `mysqlnd` plugin.

Check whether `mysqlnd` is installed like so

```
$ sudo dpkg -l | grep 'mysqlnd'
```

If it's not installed, you need to install it like so (assuming you have php5)

```
$ sudo apt-get install php5-mysqlnd
```

These commands are for *ubuntu*. If you have something else, just convert them to your appropriate OS.

Comment: Can you explain why having `mysqlnd` installed will provide integers?

Comment: It's a native driver interface. Refer this for more info (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38034996/find-on-model-gives-id-as-string-in-one-environment-and-int-in-other)

Answer (score 4):

When fetching by `select` it populates the `$attribute` internal property with raw data returned by the underlying driver, so generally the MySQL driver is configured to return all columns as strings. Here it does not casts the id attribute to integer.

You have to manually cast it to integer. you can either use `(int) $variable` syntax to cast it to integer on the fly where you are accessing the attribute of the model or you can make a mutator for that reason.

```
public function getIdAttribute($value)
{
    return (int) $value;
}
```

Or you can cast your attribute

```
protected $casts = [
    'id' => 'integer',
];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is somehow happens to my raw query doing SUM, IF, and other stuffs.

But I don't want to add more codes in model for accessor or casts like Zayn Ali's answer just for this particular query.

So my workaround is to use [MySQL cast function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html)

```php
$query->selectRaw('CAST(column_1 AS UNSIGNED) AS col1')
```

Just make sure you are aware of the SQL injection when using raw query.