# Issue with Laravel casting Int to string when fetching from server?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have my web application running on server. I tested the code in local and it works fine. I'm getting id as int from local server but string in hosted server.

Using PHP 7.3

```
$data = DB::table('users')
->select('id')
->get();

$data = $data->pluck(id);
```

(Local)
output => [1,2,3]

(Hosted)
output => ["1","2","3"]

Can any one help to resolve this issue? I can do loop to type cast but there are 100's for function in my controller. It is not possible to type cast each query.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31527050/laravel-5-controller-sending-json-integer-as-string might be of some help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use casting [Attribute Casting](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting) in your model

```
protected $casts = [ 
        'field_name1' => 'integer', 
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to a missing plugin on the production server (hosting server).
You need to install the `mysqlnd` plugin to fix the issue.

You have not mentioned which OS you are using. If it's Linux, you can check whether `mysqlnd` is installed like so

```
$ sudo dpkg -l | grep 'mysqlnd'
```

If it's not installed, you need to install it like so (assuming you have php5)

```
$ sudo apt-get install php-mysqlnd
```

*Package name might differ based on the PHP version.*

Refer my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38819501/how-to-get-laravel-query-builder-result-as-integer) for more information.