# Laravel / MySQL / Javascript stack: integer is returned as string on production, but not locally, why?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm building a CMS that uses Laravel as a RESTful API and React (+ redux) as a frontend. (I've isolated the problem to be separate from the frontend)

The CMS handles multiple sites with multiple pages. When the user adds a new page, it sends the new site data: a page title, and the ID of the parent site. (i.e. '`new-page`', '`15`')

After the API successfully saves the data, it returns the new instance fresh from the database - the page title, the parent site ID, and the new page ID (primary key) that has it has been assigned by the database.

**But**, for some reason that I cannot figure out, on the production server, the `site_id` is being returned as a string, and not an integer. (This caused a headache which I can solve with `parseInt()`, but I'd like to know what's up).

The code running on each is identical. I've confirmed on both that the `site_id` column in the database is set to `int(10) unsigned`. A call to the API that returns a site and all of its associated pages gives me these results (note the `site_id` property on each):

**Development**
[image: Development]

**Production**
[image]

Slight differences between the two environments:

**PHP**

```
php --version
 (development) PHP 5.6.24
 (production)  PHP 5.6.21
```

and

**MySQL**

```
select version()
  (development) 5.7.13
  (production)  5.6.25-73.1
```

Both are using Laravel 5.2.39.

**Why** would a value that is defined in the database as an INT be returned as a string across these two environments?

**Update:**

`mysqlnd` is installed on both my local and production environment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38819501/how-to-get-laravel-query-builder-result-as-integer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [find() on model gives id as string in one environment and int in other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38034996/find-on-model-gives-id-as-string-in-one-environment-and-int-in-other)

Comment: @ZaynAli @trajchevska it looks like this isn't the same problem, `mysqlnd` is installed on both environments. From reading those questions, it sounds like *all* ints are being returned as strings - in my case, other fields (such as the `id`) are being returned correctly

Comment: I have the same issue since I updated PHP on the server. Maybe something in the config of PHP.