# Site js file cache and behaviour

Tags: javascript, laravel, caching

Working with Laravel 5.4, having problems with js file after changes.

I made some changes to my js file, I see the changes on my local server but not on the live server.

In my htaccess I have this:

```
# One month for js
<filesMatch ".(js)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2628000, public"
</filesMatch>
```

I don't have an option to install npm etc. on the live server so I run it all on my local server and then upload the files to the live server.

I had to do some changes to try and find a solution for a different problem:

I have an orders table that holds values for shipping_method int(10)

I have one record in this table, and the shipping_method is: 2

I have a vue file that displays the Shipping method like so:

It receives data from the table, runs through it and changes the value from int to a readable string:

```
setStatusText: function(data) {
    $.each(data.data, function () {
       switch(this.Shipping){
          case 2:
             alert(this.Shipping);
             this.Shipping='Courier';
             alert(this.Shipping);
             break;
          case 3:
             this.Shipping='PostNet';
             break;
          default:
             this.Shipping='Post Office';
             break;
        }
    });
```

Running this code on my local machine I get the right word: 'Courier'

Running it on the live server I get: 'Post Office'.

That's when I added the alerts, but no matter how many times I ran: npm run dev or npm run production and uploaded all the files to the live server, nothing changes and I don't see any alerts.

I cleared the browser's cache, I pressed Ctrl+F5, nothing.

I changed the swtich default to say:

```
 break;
          default:
             this.Shipping='Courier';
             break;
```

That I do see on the live server, suddenly it now displays Courier and not Post Office

Changed it back, and again, shows me Post Office and there are no alerts on the live server, there are alerts on the local server.

So two questions here:
1. why don't I see the alerts on the js file?
2. Why do I see Post Office instead of Courier when the value in the table is definitely 2.

Thank you

Comment: Where does the `this.Shipping` come from? Are you sure the value is a number and not a string? Did you make any changes on your local server data source that you have not pushed to the live server?

Comment: Thx for trying to help Chris. The this.Shipping comes from a query from the database, and yes it is an integer, it works fine on the local machine and I uploaded this file again and again. There are no changes on the local data source, the table and field are exactly the same, int(10). Why don't I see the Alerts on the live sever so I can actually check what is the value?

Comment: By the way, I've done some other changes to the Vue file, and uploaded and these changes are visible on the live server, so I really don't understand how come I don't see the Alert and I get a different result on this specific field

Comment: Ok, I changed the field to be tinyint(1) on both servers and I changed the case to '2' instead of 2. Now it works on the live server but not on the local server. What is going on here? Why the live server sees it as string and the local as int? Very confused.

Comment: I have been bitten by this, and using [`cast`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting) is a quick fix.  The reason is probably a missing extension as [described in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38034996/find-on-model-gives-id-as-string-in-one-environment-and-int-in-other).

Comment: :) Don't Panic, nothing to see here... thank you so much, checked this post you sent. The php versions were different, but setting them to be the same didn't help. I will send this post you sent me to my host see what they say.

Comment: No, I'm wrong, the php versions were the same.... getting more and more confused, will write the host, see what they say.

Comment: So where does the data change from the PHP world to the Javascript world? How is the data getting to the client? Is the client making an HTTP request to fetch it? Can you show us that code?

Comment: @SigalZahavi neither the question I linked to nor my comment were about differing PHP versions.